# JAXB Marshal setProperty com.sun.xml.bind.CharacterEscapeHandler

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jaxb

I am trying to override the  escape of special characters in JAXB encoding.
For this I am using an interface that implements `CharacterEscapeHandler`.

Here is the interface:

```
package project1;
import com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller.CharacterEscapeHandler;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
public class MinimumEsc implements CharacterEscapeHandler {
    private MinimumEsc( ) {

        System.out.println("Function called");


    }  // no instanciation please

    public static final CharacterEscapeHandler theInstance = new MinimumEsc(); 


    public void escape(char[] ch, int start, int length, boolean isAttVal, Writer out) throws IOException {
            // avoid calling the Writerwrite method too much by assuming
            // that the escaping occurs rarely.
            // profiling revealed that this is faster than the naive code.

            System.out.println("Function called");
            int limit = start+length;
            for (int i = start; i < limit; i++) {
                char c = ch[i];
                if( c=='&' || c=='<' || c=='>' || (c=='\"' && isAttVal) ) {
                    if(i!=start)
                        out.write(ch,start,i-start);
                    start = i+1;
                 switch (ch[i]) {
                    case '&' :
                        out.write("&amp2;");
                        break;
                    case '<' :
                        out.write("&lt2;");
                        break;
                    case '>' :
                        out.write("&gt2;");
                        break;
                    case '\"' :
                        out.write("&quot2;");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if( start!=limit )
                out.write(ch,start,limit-start);
        }
}
```

From My main class i am trying to call the `marshal` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("hello world");



    try{
        //generate the java object
        Shiporder so = new Shiporder();
        so.setOrderid("123456");
        so.setOrderperson("Elio  < > ' \"  e  <> \" Khattar");


        //generate the file
        File f = new File("C:\\tst_encode.xml");
        if(!f.exists()){
          f.createNewFile();
        }


        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance("xsdobjects");
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = context.createMarshaller();
     //  Marshaller jaxbMarshaller=  new JAXBContext().newMarshaller();


        System.out.println(CharacterEscapeHandler.class.getName());
        CharacterEscapeHandler escapeHandler =  MinimumEsc.theInstance;
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.characterEscapeHandler",escapeHandler);



        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(so, f);
    }catch(JAXBException e){
        e.getCause();
        e.getErrorCode();
        e.printStackTrace();

    }catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();        
    }
}
```

I am getting this error messgae when i run it:

```
javax.xml.bind.PropertyException: name: com.sun.xml.bind.characterEscapeHandler value: project1.MinimumEsc@100bac2
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.setProperty(JAXBMarshaller.java:520)
    at project1.Class1.main(Class1.java:56)
```

can please any one help me? I have spent the last 5 hours searching the web for it and trying many solutions. Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Based on the stack trace you are using [**EclipseLink MOXy**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) as your [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) provider.  We added support for the reference implementations `com.sun.xml.bind.CharacterEscapeHandler` in EclipseLink 2.4.  Prior to that release of EclipseLink you would get the exception that you are seeing.

**UPDATE**

It is possible that you are hittin the following bug, which has been fixed in the EclipseLink 2.5.1 stream.

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/406593

You can download a nightly build from the following location:

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/nightly.php

Answer (score 0):

Check the class path，com.sun.xml.bind.CharacterEscapeHandler. In addition，check  mavan dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.6</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.6</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

If useing dependency ,it will report an error.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```